# Interactivity Level Checking In Microsoft Teams Meeting

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am looking to work upon an app that will calculate the level of interaction of all participants in Microsoft Teams Meetings. Initially i have looked into Microsoft Graph API but not able to understand where to start in this. Any lead or suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you start? Learn how to call a REST API in C#. I don't see any methods to list activity a team meeting. This method "Reads" a channel but it doesn't do much. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @nitin - There is no specific api that will provide you output as user activity/interaction during meeting. Probably [Meeting resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [User Activity in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-user-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0) can add some insights to your requirements